# Understanding the potential energy of the Atwood machine

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

So this might be a pretty simple (dumb?) question. I don't understand the choice of the potential energy on [this](http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newtonhtml/node79.html) problem. I really can't see how the "height" in the potential energy of the masses is the same as the leght of their rope sections.

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag on this type of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The horizontal line passing through the center of the pulley is being used as the reference for measuring heights. So, clearly, the height of each block of mass would be the (negative) length of the section of the rope that is connecting them to the pulley. Notice the "negative" sign. This is why the potential energy is to be written as $$U=-m_1gx-m_2g(l-x)$$ and **not** as $m_1gx+m_2g(l-x)$.

You can equivalently choose the actual ground (the local Earth-surface) to be the reference for measuring heights. Let's say that the center of the pulley is at a height of $H$ from the ground. Then, you can easily see that the heights of the blocks would be $H-x$ and $H-(l-x)$ respectively. Thus, the potential energy would be $$U=m_1g(H-x)+m_2g(H-(l-x))=(m_1g+m_2g)H-m_1gx-m_2g(l-x)$$ Notice that this is different from the potential energy calculated earlier but only by a constant $(m_1g+m_2g)H$. Since a shift in the potential energy by a constant doesn't affect the dynamics, both these expressions are physically equivalent and you can choose whichever convention you like.